# JDA - Event if new user joined to Guild

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have a problem, I am trying to code a bot using Java Discord API (JDA).
When a new user joins a server, the bot shall send a message, but my code is not working.
Code:

```java
    public class UserJoinModule extends ListenerAdapter {
        public void onGuildMemberJoined(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) throws LoginException {
            String user = event.getMember().getAsMention();
            JDA client = new JDABuilder("awesome token").build();
            final List<TextChannel> channels = client.getTextChannelsByName("awesome channel name", true);
            for (final TextChannel ch : channels) {
                ch.sendMessage("New member joined: " + user).queue();
            }
        }

    }
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was not from the listener and method I override.
I believe you have to add `GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS` to your JDABuilder.

```
builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS);
```

This fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Main.java` or whatever the file is, there is a variable of type `JDABuilder`, on it's same line of code, there is your token, a `.build()` at the end etc...

Insert this code into that line:

```java
.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
```

So it looks like this:

```java
jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("TOKEN").enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS).build();
```

For it to work, go to your [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), click your bot, from the menu on the left, click `Bot`, then scroll down and enable:

- Server Members Intent

There are still noticeable errors like registering a new client on every message and other issues, fix them, then start your bot and it shall work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```java
public class UserJoinModule extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override // USE THIS WHEN YOU WANT TO OVERRIDE A METHOD
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        String user = event.getMember().getAsMention();
        JDA client = event.getJDA(); // DO NOT CREATE A NEW JDA INSTANCE EVERY TIME
        List<TextChannel> channels = client.getTextChannelsByName("awesome channel name", true);
        for (TextChannel ch : channels) {
            ch.sendMessage("New member joined: " + user).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

And you must register this listeners in your `JDABuilder` instance, preferably you only have one of these in your entire codebase. See [`addEventListeners`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#addEventListeners(java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems in your code.

1. You are creating a new JDA client every time a member joins.
2. You are sending messages to *every* channel with that name, in *every* guild. Not just the guild that the user joined.

Here is what you want to do:

```
public class UserJoinModule extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        Guild guild = event.getGuild(); // Get the guild that the user joined.
        User user = event.getUser();    // Get the user that joined.
        JDA client = event.getJDA();    // Get the already existing JDA instance.

        List<TextChannel> channels = guild.getTextChannelsByName("awesome channel name", true); // Get the list of channels in the guild that matches that name.

        for (TextChannel channel : channels) { // Loops through the channels and sends a message to each one.
            channel.sendMessage("New member joined: " + user).queue();
        }
    }
}
```